# What is the Most efficient way to store data on the Android phone?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on storing the accelerometer data on the Android Phone. I'm wondering what's the most efficient way to store the Android Phone acceleration on the phone (e.g. write data to the file not block the thread/ write the data to the file has the highest priority).

I'm currently using **FileOutputStream**. My code to store the acceleration is as follow:

````
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        sensorReading.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));
        // Store sensor changes
        sensorVals[0] = sensorEvent.values[0];
        sensorVals[1] = sensorEvent.values[1];
        sensorVals[2] = sensorEvent.values[2];
        if (isRecording_all) {
            currentTime = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - sessionStartTime) / 1000; 
            LogPacket = createLogPacket(sensorVals, currentTime, 0, 0, 0, 0,receiveRate,sendRate);
            PACKET_NUMBER = PACKET_NUMBER+1;
            buffer.put(LogPacket);
            if (PACKET_NUMBER==10) {
                COMBINED_PACKET = buffer.array();
                try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, true)) {
                    fileOut.write(COMBINED_PACKET );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                buffer.clear();
                Arrays.fill(COMBINED_PACKET, (byte)0);
                PACKET_NUMBER=0;
            }
        }

    }```
````

Comment: Why in files? Why not in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are blocking thread where events are coming in and IO Operations can take some time. You could use something like this. When have the data coming from an event you immediately give it to a handler which keeps track of data in a queue which is safe to be accessed from many threads and uses First in first out order.This handler runs a loop in separate thread which either saves data or waits for more data to come in. This way your main thread is free to take more data events and Data handler thread's job is to save it. Both threads have producer/consumer relationship. In this example data coming at much faster rate(100ms/packet) and saving is slower (1000ms) but still all data is being saved.

```
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
    
    public class DataHandler implements Runnable {
        private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Data> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        private Thread thread;
        void start() {
            Log.i("handler", "Trying to start");
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
        void stop() {
            Log.i("handler", "Trying to stop");
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    
        void addData(Data data) {
            Log.i("handler", "Adding data");
            queue.add(data);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("handler", "Starting");
           while (true) {
               try {
                   if (queue.peek() != null) {
                       saveData(queue.take());
                   } else {
                       Log.i("handler", "Waiting");
                       Thread.sleep(1000);
                   }
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   break;
               }
           }
            Log.i("handler", "Exiting");
        }
    
    private void saveData(Data data) throws InterruptedException {
        Log.i("handler", "Saving Data");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Log.i("handler", "Saved Data");
     }
   }
```

Use it like

```
 void fakeData() throws InterruptedException {
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler();
        handler.start();
        
        Thread.sleep(100);
        handler.addData(new Data());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        handler.addData(new Data());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        handler.addData(new Data());
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        handler.stop();
    }
```